# How to test a model validation with a regex in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rspec, rspec-rails

After a bit of hacking I have come up with the following tests to make sure the regex pattern on my model validator is working correctly. I am wondering if there is a better way to test these conditions instead of building a bad string.  I want to account for any and all characters outside the approved regex pattern. Different columns may have different validators too.

**Model**

```
validates :provider_unique_id,
           presence: true,
           length: { maximum: 50 },
           format: { with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\z/ }
```

**Spec**

```
describe 'provider unique id' do
  let(:bad_string) { (0..255).map(&:chr).select { |x| x != /\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\z/ }.sample(20).join }

  it 'should exist' do
    shop.provider_unique_id = nil
    expect(shop.valid?).to be_falsey
  end

  it 'passes regex rules' do
    shop.provider_unique_id = bad_string
    expect(shop.valid?).to be_falsey
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd write if I were being extremely thorough. Imagine test-driving the validations, adding one test at a time and adding to the validations to make it pass.

```
describe '#provider_unique_id' do
  %w(a z).each do |letter|
    it "can be letter #{letter}" do
      expect_to_be_valid letter
    end
  end

  # after making this pass, I'd change the regex to use the i flag so I wouldn't need to test for Z
  it "can be uppercase" do
    expect_to_be_valid 'A'
  end

  [0, 9].each do |digit|
    it "can be digit #{digit}" do
      expect_to_be_valid digit
    end
  end

  it "can be more than one character" do
    expect_to_be_valid '00'
  end

  it "isn't nil" do
    expect_to_be_invalid nil
  end

  it "isn't blank" do
    expect_to_be_invalid ""
  end

  it "can be 50 characters long" do
    expect_to_be_valid('0' * 50)
  end

  it "can't be longer than 50 characters" do
    expect_to_be_invalid('0' * 51)
  end

  # I chose _ as a non-alphanumeric since it's the only non-alphanumeric word character.
  # That is, it's as close to a valid character as it can be without be valid.
  it "can't contain a non-alphanumeric character" do
    expect_to_be_invalid '_'
  end

  # this example forces you to add \A
  it "can't begin with a non-alphanumeric character" do
    expect_to_be_invalid '_0'
  end

  # this example forces you to add \z
  it "can't end with a non-alphanumeric character" do
    expect_to_be_invalid '0_'
  end

  def expect_to_be_valid(provider_unique_id)
    shop.provider_unique_id = provider_unique_id
    expect(shop).to be_valid
  end

  def expect_to_be_invalid(provider_unique_id)
    shop.provider_unique_id = provider_unique_id
    expect(shop).to_not be_valid
  end

end
```

I wouldn't randomly generate a bad string, because it wouldn't force you to write any additional code. I think the tests with `_` are sufficient. Note that there are many more characters than ASCII 0-255, and it would be impractical to test them all.

You could imagine boundary-checking the ranges in the regex (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`) by testing characters that come immediately before and after each range, but it's unlikely that someone would write code that would incorrectly include those characters, so I wouldn't go that far.

Comment: I would like to test all cases where the regex pattern does not match.  I am not sure this catches this, as it only test for specific cases.  You did identify for me that the random character selector is truthy because it may select results during a given test run that pass but not in others.  I wonder if I should break this out into multiple tests that look for things like all symbols, all numbers, stuff like that...

Comment: Again, you can't really test all negative cases; there are too many. The question is whether writing the next test would motivate you to change the code. I did just add two more tests: I realized that I hadn't forced the regex to have ranges. Testing z and 9 doesn't prevent you from writing a regex that only matches a, z, 0 and 9, but it's unlikely that anyone would do that, so I wouldn't test even more valid cases.